# I have lost the Logical Volume name on a disk partition and am trying to recover/rebuild it

Tags: hard-drive, catalina, partition

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro that has 2 internal fusion drives and an external LaCie USB drive and can (normally) boot into 4 iterations of Mac OS: Snow Leopard, Mavericks, El Capitan, and Catalina. This is so that I can run older as well as newer software. The first system drive is partitioned into Snow Leopard and Mavericks (even though the partition name still shows up as "Mountain Lion"), the second system drive has El Capitan on it, and the 2 TB LaCie drive is partitioned into two 1 TB partitions, "LaCie" and "Catalina." It is true that I am using Dosdude1's Catalina patcher to run Catalina on my MacBook Pro and I had to install it on an external drive because for some stupid reason I hadn't partitioned the El Cap drive when I had installed it. Recently I had booted up the machine into Catalina, then did other stuff for the rest of the day. When I tried to use it later that evening I had found that it had locked up. The next day I tried to boot up Catalina, but after it ran the patcher program failed to find the partition.
[image]

I then used Disk Drill to recover the data on the Catalina partition. The partition was showing a GUID tag instead of a name and I tried to use some instructions on a previous Ask Different thread to try to repair it but ended up removing the GUID tag by the looks of it. In terminal that Catalina partition was showing up as disk2s3.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.